# where is the const-ness in this lambda capture argument introduced?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, asio

This code compiles correctly.

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Message { int msg; };

// never mind global variables, just for the sake of making this a minimal example
extern asio::ip::tcp::socket mysocket;

void handler(std::shared_ptr<Message> pmsg, asio::error_code error, size_t nbytes);

void readMessage()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Message> pmsg{ new Message };
    asio::async_read(mysocket, asio::buffer(&pmsg->msg, sizeof(int)),
            [pmsg](auto err, auto nbytes) { handler(pmsg, err, nbytes); });
}
```

However, when I add a reference to the first argument of the handler function

```
void handler(std::shared_ptr<Message>& pmsg, asio::error_code error, size_t nbytes);
```

the code no longer compiles, complaining that I am trying to convert pmsg from a `const std::shared_ptr<Message>&` to a `std::shared_ptr<Message>&`.

To get it to work again, I have to introduce a `const_cast<std::shared_ptr<Message>&>` in the call to the handler.

Where is the const-ness introduced?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`psmg` is captured by value, so it is read only inside closure. If you need it to be modifiable (because that is required by `handler`) you have to add `mutable` to the lambda:

```
[pmsg](auto err, auto nbytes) mutable { handler(pmsg, err, nbytes); });
```

[Live demo based on BoostAsio](https://godbolt.org/z/eoEGf453n)

---

When `pmsg` is capture by value, the compiler is allowed to make one implicit conversion, so from `pmsg` is created temporary `shared_ptr` instance and passed to `handler`, but temporary object cannot be bound to *Lvalue reference* (it could be work with const *lvalue* ref).